# c# programmatically set or Clear 'Accessed' meta info of a file

Tags: c#, windows, fileinfo

There is an 'Accessed' meta data which is shown as part of the properties window of a file.is there a programmatically way to delete this info or set it to something else?
Thank you
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125382/changing-the-file-creation-date-does-not-work/17126045#17126045

Answer (score 1):

The `FileInfo` class can take care of this for you.

```
[TestMethod]
public void SetLastAccessTime()
{
    String fileName = @"D:\Sample.txt";

    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
    fi.CreationTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);
    fi.LastWriteTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);
    fi.LastAccessTime = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2);
}
```

And, this is what the file properties looks like after this code has run.

[image: File properties after this code runs]

Answer (score 1):

After a small search I found this in  [File.SetLastAccessTime Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setlastaccesstime(v=vs.110).aspx)

Haven't used it myself but according to MSDN you can set the Access time with this:

```
File.SetLastAccessTime
```